# JSTree lazy load not fetching children

Tags: javascript, jstree

Using the latest jstree. I can load all nodes but now i am trying to lazy load the nodes. When I expand the last visible node, no GET is made.

.js

```
$('#nodes').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'data' : {
            'url': function(node) {
                return node.id === '#' ? 'api/mycontroller' : 'api/mycontroller/' + node.id;
            },
            "data" : function (node) {
                return { "id": node.id};
            }

        }
    }
});
```

The returned JSON data from the initial call is 
[{"state":{"opened":true,"disabled":false,"selected":false},"id":"-100","text":"Node1 Text","children":[{"state":{"opened":false,"disabled":false,"selected":false},"id":"0","text":"Node2 Text","children":[true]}]}]

When I click on Node 2, nothing happens. I am watching fiddler and no call is made. I verified it using dev tools networking. A folder with no data appears

Answer (score 0):

I tried to serialize a "node" object that had a list of objects.

```
children = new List<object>();
```

When using this collection with node objects everything was fine. However if you look at the serialization of the Boolean true that I listed, that is not correct. So I could not just shove in a boolean into the collection.

a few options i explored.... 
1. write a custom json converter
2. derive 2 objects. One with a List of children nodes. A second with a boolean

that solved the problem. I rolled with 2 because it was faster and I am just prototyping some stuff. 1 would probably be a more elegant solution.